# how to catch overscrolling effect in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

How to catch overscrolling effect in windows phone 7? Example of ovescrolling effect?
I want to add new rectangle when user do overscroll of listbox.

Example of overscrolling:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8 you can use ScrollViewer or Telerik RadDataBoundListBox

Answer (score 1):

They are compression events. You can take a look at this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/30/windows-phone-mango-change-listbox-how-to-detect-compression-end-of-scroll-states.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Height for the ScrollViewer and the rectangles inside the specified height of the scrollviewer.